# Second Order Filter with DC offset

Tags: active-filter, voltage-reference

The circuit below takes the signal from a current transformer, depicted as I1, convert it to voltage through R9 and go to the second order filter U1. I want to add an offset to the current transformer signal so that it swings around Vcc/2 instead of crossing the zero point, so I can process the signal with an ADC. Is it safe to use a voltage divider with a voltage follower as shown? The circuit does not have specific components values, but would the concept idea work?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to use a voltage divider with a voltage follower as shown?

I think it will work very nice.
Ideally Vcc is constant, R10 and R11 would work as a perfect voltage divider and U3 as perfect follower.
So, points to counter are their imperfections:

- How stable is Vcc? (I think  fluctuations are probably compensated well enough with C4)
- What is the tolerance of R10 and R11? You might want 0.1% tolerance for both resistors.
- Is the input bias current of U3 low enough? It should be low enough compared to the current total current running through R10 in order to not alter the desired divided voltage yoo much.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to use a voltage divider with a voltage follower as shown?

Of course, you've put the opamp in an inverting configuration, with the positive terminal having an offset. Similar to a [differential amp](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html) but with no resistors on the positive terminal

Vout for U2 would be:

\$ Vout  = -\frac{R7 }{ R6}*Vref + \frac{R7+R6 }{ R6}*Vpos\$

Answer (score 1):

If your opamps can swing around 0, then you can just add the ref voltage to the final stage on U2.